# Classical Internet routing vs. Swarm routing (such as Ant routing)?

Tags: optimization, swarm-intelligence

Is it possible to mention the drawbacks/advantages of **Swarm routing** (such as Ant routing etc) in comparison with **classical routing** algorithms in communication networks in a general view?

In other words, what will we gain if we replace a classical routing algorithm with a swarm routing based algorithm?

Can we compare these two type of routing algorithms in a general view to mention their to count the drawbacks/advantages?

The main purpose of this question is to define applications of each of those routing approaches. Which one is more decentralized? And which one has more efficient performance?

Here is my personal opinion (I am not sure about it) :

**classical** internet routing in **more centralized** than **swarm** routing (such as **ACO** based routing) which does **not** use any **routing table and router** to avoid moving towards **centralization** where those routing tables and routers **can be manipulated** (as a **point of failure**). Instead, **classical** internet routing may be **faster** than **swarm** based routing. Briefly, **classical** may be **more centralized**, but **faster** and on the other side, **swarm** based is **more decentralized** but may be **slower**. Am I wrong?

**Please note** that when I say "**decentralized**", I mean a network like "**ad hoc networks**" that do **not** rely on **routers or access points** (as a **point of failure**) to avoid moving towards **centralization**. In case of using routers or access point, some kind of **centralization** is inherent. With this definition of **decentralization**, it seems **Swarm** based routing such as **Ant routing** would be **more decentralized**. **However, I am not sure about it and that's my main question.**